# VueJS not reference NestJS ServeRoot Base path

Tags: vue.js, nestjs

I am using the NestJS ServeStaticModule to resolve my admin and client front-ends to two different paths, /client and /admin.

When we try to load this page Vue is attempting to load the JS, CSS and other local assets without the /{prefix} in-front resulting in a 404.

Is there a way to work around this, do I need to define at a Vue level what the route is going to be prior to building?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to add the pass path to my VueRouter when in production. For example if you are trying to replicate this is how it would look:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';

Vue.use(Router);

const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '/admin' : undefined ),
  routes: [...]
});

export default router;
```